# Score based on the total length inputted

Tags: python

Expected output

- Input: "man" then score = 3,
- Input: "hello" then score = 4
- Input: "rationed" then score = 8,

but it will only output 0

```
score = 0
guess_word = input("Guess a word: ")
secret_word = ["man","hello","brunch","awesome","great","estuary","rationed"]
while guess_word == secret_word:
    if len(guess_word) == 2 and len(guess_word) ==3 :
        score += 1
    elif len(guess_word) == 4:
        score += 2
    elif len(guess_word) == 5:
        score += 3
    elif len(guess_word) == 6 and len(guess_word) == 7:
        score += 5
    elif len(guess_word) == 8:
        score += 8
print(f"your score: {score}")
```

Comment: The condition `guess_word == secret_word` is never true: in the first place, because `guess_word` is a string and `secret_word` is a list of strings.

Comment: `guess_word` comes from `input`, it's a string. `secret_word` is a list of strings. `guess_word == secret_word` will **always** be false. Your loop never runs.

Comment: I need some clarification. how did assign the value in man and hello based on length or something? if it considers the length hello length is 5 but you gave 4?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are comparing a string with a list. So instead of doing

```
while guess_word == secret_word:
```

you should be using `in`

```
if guess_word in secret_word:
```

Secondly if you use a while as you did it will stay in an infinite loop

```
while guess_word == secret_word:
```

Thus either like what i did change it to if (single iteration)

```
if guess_word in secret_word:
```

or put `guess_word = input(guess_word)` within a while true loop (multiple iteration)

```
while True:
    guess_word = input("Guess a word: ")
    if guess_word not in secret_word:
        break
```

This allows guess_word to get updated

Last but not least if you input man you will only get score + 1 as determined by the following code: (BTW you should be using or since `len(guess_word) == 2 or len(guess_word) ==3` are mutually exclusive)

```
if len(guess_word) == 2 or len(guess_word) ==3 :
    score += 1
```

if you want it to add according to the scores you gave you should be doing

```
score += len(guess_word)
```

In sum your code would look something like:

```
score = 0
secret_word = ["man","hello","brunch","awesome","great","estuary","rationed"]
while True:
    guess_word = input("Guess a word: ")
    if len(guess_word) == 2 or len(guess_word) ==3 :
        score += len(guess_word)
    elif len(guess_word) == 4:
        score += len(guess_word)
    elif len(guess_word) == 5:
        score += len(guess_word)
    elif len(guess_word) == 6 and len(guess_word) == 7:
        score += len(guess_word)
    elif len(guess_word) == 8:
        score += len(guess_word)

    if guess_word not in secret_word:
        break
    print("Congrats! Your score is now " + str(score))

print(f"Your Final score: {score}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I definitely need some practicing to do , props to you!!!

Comment: I've added score += score so it adds the total

Comment: @JonathanRimin You wouldn't need the variable total in my opinion so i just dropped it and replaced it with score